# Android L ViewOutlineProvider, strange behavior when created rect side is out of screen

Tags: android, view, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a strange problem with the `ViewOutlineProvider` for a clipped `View` on Android L.

I try to increase the size of the clip circle while moving the finger over the screen (x coordinates etc.). (Like on the Android L lock screen, left and right icons, which increases when you drag your finger in the specific direction)

The size changing works perfectly, until the clip bounds reaches the left or bottom border of the screen, after this the clip bounds are disappeared and i don't have any clip bounds. (Nothing rounded)

[image]

[image]

The Rect values, which causes the problem:

```
Rect(-1, 1033 - 101, 1136) (Rect(left, top - right, bottom))
```

I initiate and add the view, which i want to clip, in this way:

```
toClipView = new ViewClipTest(getContext());
toClipView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
addView(toClipView);
```

The clip view has a gray background and a red `ImageView` as child, it extends a `FrameLayout`

Update code for clip bounds scaling (is called from a `onTouchEvent`, while `ACTION_MOVE`):

```
public void scaleClipbounds(float convertScale) {//-1 to 1
    float scale = ...;

    currentScale = scale;

    ...

    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setOutlineProvider(new ClipOutline(createScaledRect(currentScale)));
            invalidate();
        }
    });

}

...

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            newX = event.getRawX();
            newY = event.getRawY();

            float newScale = ...;

            scaleClipbounds(newScale);
 ...
```

My `ViewOutlineProvider`:

```
public class ClipOutline extends ViewOutlineProvider {

    private Rect outerLineRect;

    public ClipOutline(Rect outerLineRect) {
        this.outerLineRect = outerLineRect;
    }

    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setOval(outerLineRect);
    }
}
```

Xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.ClipViewTestContainer
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I initiate the clip bounds with the same rect, which causes the issue, everything works well, until I try to increase the bounds while `onTouch` again.

What is my mistake here? Or how can I force that the clip bounds can be set out of the screen boundaries? Is there a more fluent way to implement such kind of feature, instead of using an `ViewOutlineProvider`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your rect you're passing into setOval (-1, 1033 - 101, 1136) has size 102 x 103, which means your outline won't be a circle, and thus won't be eligible for clipping. Only circles, rects, and round rects can be clipped to, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#canClip()

Additionally, you can significantly simplify your runnable / outline provider creation by, within scaleClipBounds, updating an existing custom outline provider, and calling View#invalidateOutline().

```
public void scaleClipbounds(float convertScale) {
    ...
    mOutlineProvider.setRect(rect)
    invalidateOutline()
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Used a square rect and re-factored the runnable. The funny thing is, that nothing happens with this solution (tried several times). The invalidateOutline() call seems to be ignored.

I think I will implement my feature in a complete other way. But thank you for your help!

Comment: You may need to call invalidate() in addition to invalidateOutline()

Comment: Thanks @Chris Craik on some L devices, it needs to call invalidate() and invalidateOutline() to make it work